# CMA Net - How to export all statistics ? (In Excel/XLS)

Tags: industrial-robot

On the lower-right of the screen, there is an "Archive" button, from which I go to the dialog box/window where there are **Delete**, **Delete all**, **Export** and **Load** options, but there is no "**Export All**" ...

The robot in question is manufactured by:

https://www.cmarobot.it/intelligent_painting_robot/index.php

If I attach a keyboard to the robot computer, can I mark everything by Ctrl + A keyboard combination ? Or maybe with Shift + Arrow up/down... ?

I can provide more photos if necessary.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: it seems like you have access to the device .... why are you asking us about the keyboard and about possible key combinations?

Comment: My guess is that this is a touchscreen @jsotola.

Comment: Yes, I confirm - it is a touch display.
I will try with a keyboard and keep you posted about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved !**

No need to connect a keyboard.

I went to D:\cmafiles\STATS and there is the whole list of files with the working statistics in XLS format. I've copied all of them on my USB Flash memory.

Thank you everyone.

[image]